# DNS Delegation www

Tags: dns

I've delegated www to my company's load balancer.  The load balancer then answers with an A record based upon which of my company's web servers has the least load.  It will also direct them to a different data center if the primary campus has an internet outage.  This works great for www.mycompany.com. (example)

```
www                 NS     load-balancer-1.mycompany.com.
                    NS     load-balancer-2.mycompany.com.
load-balancer-1     A      1.2.3.4
load-balancer-2     A      5.6.7.8
```

What do I do with the record for mycompany.com?  Should I remove the A record for "mycompany.com"?  What will my customers see when they type

```
http://mycompany.com
```

in their web browser?  What is the best way to handle this?  I would like my load balancer to provide the answer to "http://www.mycompany.com" and "http://mycompany.com" based upon its monitoring of my web servers, data center availability, and all the other goodness that the load balancer provides.